# Is continuous a better solution in this sentence?

Tags: past-simple

The two men were thieves and the TV they **were carrying** was his TV!

just wondering if "is carrying" could be changed in carried because the action was completed. He helped them carry to their car

https://www.liveworksheets.com/worksheets/en/English_as_a_Second_Language_(ESL)/Past_tenses/Past_simple_vs_Past_continuous_ry1019967hg

Comment: You can use ***carried*** in your context regardless of whether the action was completed at "narrative reference time". *He realised that the TV they carried was actually his own, being stolen. So he ran over and shot them before they could put it in their van and drive away.* In a context like that, ***were carrying*** and ***carried*** are semantically equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

At the time he was thinking, they had already finished carrying the TV, but he was thinking about the time that he saw them, and at the time they were in the process of carrying the TV. The best way to describe his thoughts is to use past continuous:

> The two men were thieves and the TV they **were carrying** was his TV!

Comment: Many native peakers would omit the second 'TV'. The TV they were carrying was his!